# How to Use Take and Skip Function in MVC

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-ajax

I want to Load Data and skip previous data which already append in the view using skip and take count in mvc.Here is my View where i am getting data

```
var skipCount = 5; 
var takeCount = 5; 

function loadMore() {
  $(window).bind('scroll', bindScroll);
  itemCount = takeCount;
  skipCount += takeCount;
  setTimeout(function () {
    getFeed();
  },100);            
}

function bindScroll() {
  if ($(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width() > $('.tile-area').width() - 130) {
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
    loadMore();
  }
}

function getFeed() {             
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: "/PlanetFeed/PlanetfeedPartial",
    dataType: "html",
    data: { id: planetFeedOwnerId, filterType: filterType, taggedItemGraphId: taggedItemGraphId, itemCount: takeCount, SkipCount: skipCount },      //"feedGraphId=10696",
    success: function (data) {
    if (data === null) {

    } else {
      $('.tile-area-title').html("");
      var div = $('.planetFeed:last');
      div.after(data);
      skipCount += takeCount + 1;
    }                                
  });
}
```

And Here is My Controller Where I am Passing Parameter

```
public ActionResult PlanetfeedPartial(Guid id, string filterType, Guid taggedItemGraphId, int itemCount, int SkipCount)
{
  var planetfeedsOrder = from p in db.PlanetFeeds
                         where p.CurrentState != 1
                         join s in searchTag on p.PlanetFeedGraphId equals s.SecondaryTaggedGraphItemId
                         join g in db.Graphs on p.PlanetFeedItemGraphId equals g.GraphID
                         join u in db.UserInfos on p.PlanetFeedPosterId equals u.UserInfoID
                         orderby p.PostDate descending
                         select new PlanetFeedViewModel
                         {            
                           Username = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,                                          
                           isRootFeed = p.isRootFeed,
                           PostDate = p.PostDate,
                           CommentCount = g.CountResponses,
                           CountPositiveReactions = g.CountPositiveReactions,
                           CountNegativeReactions = g.CountNegativeReactions,
                           ItemID = g.ItemID,
                           UserLevel = u.UserLevel,
                           CurrentState = p.CurrentState,
                           Address = g.Address
                         };
  return PartialView("_PlanetfeedPartial", planetfeedsOrder.OrderByDescending(p => p.PostDate).Skip(SkipCount).Take(itemCount).ToList());
}
```

I am not getting proper Data and every time when i am loading data in scroll getting different data not in a proper sequence and all data not loading

Comment: I suggest you try to use parameters for skip/take. Your code is a tangle of methods calling one another and changing global variables at several places. I can't debug this in my mind.

Comment: @GertArnold Could You Give Some More Hint to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var planetfeedsOrder = (from p in db.PlanetFeeds
                         where p.CurrentState != 1
                         join s in searchTag on p.PlanetFeedGraphId equals s.SecondaryTaggedGraphItemId
                         join g in db.Graphs on p.PlanetFeedItemGraphId equals g.GraphID
                         join u in db.UserInfos on p.PlanetFeedPosterId equals u.UserInfoID
                         orderby p.PostDate descending
                         select new PlanetFeedViewModel
                         {            
                           Username = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName,                                          
                           isRootFeed = p.isRootFeed,
                           PostDate = p.PostDate,
                           CommentCount = g.CountResponses,
                           CountPositiveReactions = g.CountPositiveReactions,
                           CountNegativeReactions = g.CountNegativeReactions,
                           ItemID = g.ItemID,
                           UserLevel = u.UserLevel,
                           CurrentState = p.CurrentState,
                           Address = g.Address
                         }).orderby(o=>o.id).skip(100);
```

skip One hundred then shows your data and create order by any id or string that you want sequence data.

Comment: My id is GUID ..it will make some change or it will work fine ?

Comment: GUID is not sorted default ,so when insert record in db any date here?

Comment: Yes using p.Postdate but one thing when page will load it will skip first 100 values?

Comment: made OrderByDescending(o=>o.PostDate).take(100); that will return top 100 records in your grid.

Comment: ..did u get my requirement..i want first 5 value to be display in view and after that next 5 and so on .. so last values which are preloaded can be skipped /

Comment: what is you rendering method ? you are using webgrid or somethings else?

Comment: i am using partial view to render

Comment: dude ,for pagination ? if i give you fever so you use the webgrid because it is very nice component for rendering data as well as for pagination.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71862/discussion-between-neeraj-mehta-and-rughaani).

Comment: `var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage : true, rowsPerPage : 5, selectionFieldName : "selectedRow", ajaxUpdateContainerId : "grid-content");
 grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);`  and